# pkgbuild produces a package that fails to install

Tags: macos, codesign, pkgbuild, productbuild

I am trying to create a simple macOS package that installs a tool in `/usr/local/`:

`hello.c`:

```cc
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  printf("Hello World\n");
  return 0;
}
```

`distribution.plist`:

```xml
<installer-gui-script minSpecVersion="1">
    <product id="net.world" version="1.0"/>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <choices-outline>
      <line choice="net.world.hello"/>
    </choices-outline>
    <choice id="net.world.hello" title="Hello">
      <pkg-ref id="net.world.hello">h1.pkg</pkg-ref>
    </choice>
</installer-gui-script>
```

`build.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
cc -o hello hello.c
mkdir -p local/bin
cp hello local/bin/
codesign -s - -i net.world.hello local/bin/hello
pkgbuild --identifier net.world.hello \
         --root local \
         --install-location /usr/local \
         h1.pkg
productbuild --distribution distribution.plist --resources . hello.pkg
```

The build scrips produces a package `hello.pkg`. However, when I try to install it, I get

```
<Debug>: Product archive /Users/foo/hello.pkg trustLevel=100
<Error>: PKInstallRequest: failed to initialize. Error: Error Domain=PKInstallRequestErrorDomain Code=2 "Specifier Description:<PKPackageSpecifier>:
    {
        URL = "file:///Users/foo/h1.pkg";
        identifier = "net.world.hello";
        options = 0;
        version = 0;
    }" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specifier Description:<PKPackageSpecifier>:
    {
        URL = "file:///Users/foo/h1.pkg";
        identifier = "net.world.hello";
        options = 0;
        version = 0;
    }}
<Debug>: External component packages (1) trustLevel=100 (trust evaluation failed)
<Debug>: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlanReturningError:]: location = file://localhost
<Debug>: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlanReturningError:]: file://localhost/Users/foo/h1.pkg
<Error>: Failed to locate package at path /Users/foo/h1.pkg (h1.pkg -- file://localhost/Users/foo/hello.pkg)
<Error>: Install failed: The Installer can’t locate the data it needs to install the software. Check your install media or internet connection and try again, or contact the software manufacturer for assistance.
```

The package build runs on Github Action (macOS 11/Xcode 13.2).
What is wrong with this setup, and how can I create a distributable package that installs in `/usr/local`?

Comment: Have you tried assigning permissions to the component pkg via `chmod 755 h1.pkg`

Comment: No, but it is not meant to be executed, and it is nowhere documented that it should be executable.

Comment: The trustlevel 100 error usually indicates a permissions problem, or a signing certificate problem.

Comment: Yes, but this is not the cause. I also tried `-allowUntrusted` without success. Generally, one can install unsigned packages on macOS; just this one doesn't work.

Comment: A distribution package is not an unsigned package.

Comment: Not sure I understand this. One can ofcourse distribute unsigned packages; they require additional steps on user's side (Context menu --> Open, or [temporarily] switching off the gatekeeper).

Comment: Yes, I meant of course in only the default security mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a number of attempts, I found that it pragmatically works if the components get a version assigned, i.e. `pkgbuild --version 1.2.3 …`, or in the `distribution.plist`. This is somehow surprising, as the documentation doesn't state that a version is required (it says that the version is then set to 0 and it cannot decide whether it is an upgrade or a downgrade).

It has however nothing to do with the signature or permissions.